# SQL Error of Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I was executing this query in SQL but is giving me an error like this "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a sub query." Is there anyone who can help me with it. I am really stuck. Thank you
Here is my query.

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
      ,SUM(case 
           when [code] = 1  Then 
           case 
             when exists(select * from [sampletab] where [id] = [id]and [code] = 2) then

                case when exists(select * from [sampletab] where [id] = [id] and [code] = 4) then 100 
                else 100
                end 

               else 100
               end    
           when [code] = 8 then 200
           when code = 2 then 100
           when code = 4 then 100

      end
      ) as "totl"

  FROM [test].[dbo].[sampletab]
  GROUP BY id , name
```

[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioPIR.png)

Comment: `[id] = [id]` suggests that your query is not going to do anything useful.  How about starting with sample data and desired results?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Actually I want to calculate few values like if customer have id =1 and he has code 1, 2, 4 then it must be count one time. I am trying to attach a screenshot of sample data i got but don't know how to add a screen shot here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of your query that should actually get some results.

```
SELECT
Id,
Name,
SUM(ScorePerCode)
FROM (
    SELECT 
    id,
    name,
    CASE WHEN code = 1 THEN 100
        WHEN code = 2 THEN 50
        WHEN code = 4 THEN 20
        WHEN code = 8 THEN 200
        END AS ScorePerCode
    FROM [test].[dbo].[sampletab]
) X
GROUP BY Id, Name
```

This section of your query is meaningless, and is the source of your problems. You're always going to arrive at a value of 100, if this query ever stood a chance of working...

```
 WHEN [code] = 1
         THEN 
            CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [sampletab] WHERE [code] = 2 ) 
            THEN 
                CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [sampletab] WHERE [code] = 4) 
                THEN 100
                ELSE 100 END 
            ELSE 100 END
```

Comment: Hi, Please have a look at attached screenshot of my data. I actually want to SUM the value. I need to first group by all records on the basis of id. Now if one customer have 1, 2 , 4 all of these codes then its corresponding value which is 100 should be calculated only once and in other case if he only have 1 code from (1,2,4 ) then again he will get 100 points which needs to be calculated . Does it make sense now?

Comment: I'm still not 100% clear, but I'm guessing the first query in my answer above is what you want...

Comment: as you can see in my attached screenshot of my sample data, there is a customer with id =1 , name = ali but he have four different codes, I want to give him 100 points even if he have three point(1, 2,4) only once and 200 points for code 8. so for ali it will be total 300. I do not want to give him 100 for having code =1 and another 100 for having code =2. I just want to give him only 100 points for all three codes(1, 2, 4) and 200 points for code = 8  Does it make sense now?

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. Really strange, but it makes sense. Give me a minute and I'll update again. What happens if he has 1 & 2, but not 4, or 1 & 4, but not 2? Any partial credit, or just 100 points if all 3, or 0 if not?

Comment: if he have all three then it will be 100, if he have only 1,2 then again it will be only 100 and if he only have 1 then again only 100.  Code(1) = 100, Code(1,2,4) = 100,  Code (2, 4) = 100,   Code(1,2) = 100

Comment: I have changed the code value for code =2 and code =4 as 100. now i think it is clear. It should count only 100 if he have all three code or only 2 or 1 code, it should give that customer only once 100 points.